# If a person is 'pompous', what noun would describe them?

Tags: word-choice

I'm thinking there must be a word like 'prig', but I can't bring one to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Thesaurus.com has some synonyms for "pompous person", but you're right, there doesn't seem to be a suitable single-word term. The most usual idiom for a pompous person is "pompous ass".

[Cambridge Dictionary: ass](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ass)

[Thesaurus.com: pompous person](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pompous%20person)

Comment: It seems a shame. If you wanted to call someone a pompous person, perhaps the portmanteau of 'pomperson' would do.

Comment: @AppleCrumbles I'll add it to my dictionary.